# Can't write capital M

Tags: emacs, lisp

I suppose my problem is pretty obvious, but I don't know Lisp and can't figure it out. Every time I try to write a capital "M" in a python file it won't work (It seems to think that's a start of a shortcut). My guess is that's somewhere in a module or my .emacs file it tries to bind something to Alt + something. But instead it binds it to capital M something. Here's my .emacs file (of which I copied most of it from the net):

```
; load-path setting is only needed if the directory you put
; weblogger.el in isn't already in your load-path
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")

; Remap Ctrl-tab to M-Tab
(define-key function-key-map [(control tab)] [?\M-\t])

(require 'ipython)
(define-key py-mode-map (kbd "M-") 'anything-ipython-complete)
(define-key py-shell-map (kbd "M-") 'anything-ipython-complete)
(define-key py-mode-map (kbd "C-c M") 'anything-ipython-import-modules-from-buffer)

(require 'python-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))

(require 'python-pep8)
(require 'python-pylint)

(require 'lambda-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lambda-mode 1)

(require 'comint)
(define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "M-") 'comint-next-input)
(define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "M-") 'comint-previous-input)
(define-key comint-mode-map [down] 'comint-next-matching-input-from-input)
(define-key comint-mode-map [up] 'comint-previous-matching-input-from-input)

(autoload 'pylookup-lookup "pylookup")
(autoload 'pylookup-update "pylookup")
(setq pylookup-program "~/.emacs.d/pylookup/pylookup.py")
(setq pylookup-db-file "~/.emacs.d/pylookup/pylookup.db")
(global-set-key "\C-ch" 'pylookup-lookup)

(autoload 'autopair-global-mode "autopair" nil t)
(autopair-global-mode)
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook
          #'(lambda () (setq autopair-dont-activate t)))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (push '(?' . ?')
                    (getf autopair-extra-pairs :code))
              (setq autopair-handle-action-fns
                    (list #'autopair-default-handle-action
                          #'autopair-python-triple-quote-action))))

(require 'python-pep8)
(require 'python-pylint)

(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)

(autoload 'pylookup-lookup "pylookup")
(autoload 'pylookup-update "pylookup")
(setq pylookup-program "~/.emacs.d/pylookup/pylookup.py")
(setq pylookup-db-file "~/.emacs.d/pylookup/pylookup.db")
(global-set-key "\C-ch" 'pylookup-lookup)

;; Initialize Rope
(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
(setq ropemacs-enable-autoimport t)

(require 'auto-complete)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)

;(when (require 'auto-complete nil t)
;  (require 'auto-complete-yasnippet)
;  (require 'auto-complete-python)
;  (require 'auto-complete-css)
;  (require 'auto-complete-cpp)
;  (require 'auto-complete-emacs-lisp)
;  (require 'auto-complete-semantic)
;  (require 'auto-complete-gtags))

;  (global-auto-complete-mode t)
;  (setq ac-auto-start 3)
;  (setq ac-dwim t)
;  (set-default 'ac-sources '(ac-source-yasnippet ac-source-abbrev ac-source-words-in-buffer ac-source-files-in-current-dir ac-source-symbols))

; (load-library "init_python")
```

Any idea where I should start looking for the problem? A simple search or any other way to debug the files in the .emacs-directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks wrong to me:

```
(define-key py-mode-map (kbd "M-") 'anything-ipython-complete)
(define-key py-shell-map (kbd "M-") 'anything-ipython-complete)
(define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "M-") 'comint-next-input)
(define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "M-") 'comint-previous-input)
```

`kbd` expect a full binding, but you're trying to bind <kbd>M-</kbd>
to some functions. I suspect a letter is missing.

i.e.

```
(define-key py-mode-map (kbd "M-TAB") 'anything-ipython-complete)
```

Here, <kbd>M</kbd> stands for `META` which is usually bound to `ALT`
or `ESC`.

By the way, you can do <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> to see
minor mode bindings starting with `X`.

Comment: Writing the string `C-h` (and similar) as two kbd tags is confusing: it absolutely reads as pressing the 'C' key and the 'h' key, which is not at all what you want to say. You ought to either use a single kbd tag, or otherwise be explicit about the name of the modifier key(s), and write `Ctrl` and `Meta` instead of `C` and `M`.

Comment: Ok. Thnx, i look into it after work (and probably accept the answer) :)